# IPhone, trying to play around getting error -46, Domain NSOSStatusErrorDomain

Tags: iphone, ios

I had code in a old sdk 3.0 project of mine that is not working with the new sdk.  I have copied the code in a very simple project (just a uivue project and I put the sound code in onload) to make sure nothing else I did is messing it up.

I'm getting a error code -46, Domain NSOSStatusErrorDomain

code

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"EvilDrop-2.mp3", 
[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath]]];
NSError *error;
audioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url error:&error];
audioPlayer.volume=1.0;
audioPlayer.numberOfLoops= 0;
[audioPlayer play];
audioPlayer.delegate = self;

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because you're not using `-[NSString stringWithFormat:` correctly. However, you don't need that method.

Try this code:

```
NSURL *myURL;
myURL = [[NSBundle mainBundle]
          URLForResource:@"MyFile"
          withExtension:@"mp3"];
```